# Spring cache not working with EHCache+JCache

Tags: java, spring, ehcache, spring-cache, jcache

I'm trying to integration the ehcache implementation of jcache to work with spring. So I have a facade defined like this:

```
@Component(value = "sampleFacade")
 @CacheDefaults(cacheName = "default")
 public class SampleFacadeImpl implements SampleFacade
 {

   @Override
   @CacheResult(cacheName = "site")
    public SitePojo getSiteForUid(final String uid)
    {
        System.out.println("getting the site for uid: " + uid);

        final SitePojo pojo = new SitePojo();
        pojo.setUid(uid);
        pojo.setUrl(uid);

        return pojo;
    }
}
```

and a java based configuration that looks like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableCaching(mode = AdviceMode.PROXY)
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.test" })
public class TestConfig implements CachingConfigurer
{
   @Resource
   public ApplicationContext context;

   @Override
   @Bean(name = { "defaultKeyGenerator", "keyGenerator" })
   public KeyGenerator keyGenerator() {
       return new SimpleKeyGenerator();
   }

   @Override
   @Bean(name = { "defaultCacheManager", "cacheManager" })
   public CacheManager cacheManager() {
       final JCacheCacheManager cacheManager = new JCacheCacheManager();
       cacheManager.setCacheManager((javax.cache.CacheManager) context.getBean("cacheManagerFactoryBean"));

       return cacheManager;
   }

   @Bean(name = { "defaultCacheManagerFactoryBean", "cacheManagerFactoryBean" })
   protected JCacheManagerFactoryBean defaultCacheManagerFactoryBean() {
       return new JCacheManagerFactoryBean();
   }
}
```

and a test that calls the facade 10 times:

```
@Test
public void testGetSiteForUid() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        assertNotNull(sampleFacade.getSiteForUid("uid"));
    }
}
```

but the result is passing through the method 10 times:

```
getting the site for uid: uid
getting the site for uid: uid
getting the site for uid: uid
getting the site for uid: uid
getting the site for uid: uid
getting the site for uid: uid
getting the site for uid: uid
getting the site for uid: uid
getting the site for uid: uid
getting the site for uid: uid
```

You can find a sample project to reproduce it here:
https://github.com/paranoiabla/spring-cache-test

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JCache support is a new feature of Spring 4.1. You are using 4.0.4 which does not have this support yet.

Spring Framework 4.1 has not been released yet. You can try a snapshot by adding the following to your project

```
<repositories>
  <repository>
    <id>spring-snapshot</id>
    <name>Springframework Snapshot Repository</name>
    <url>http://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
    <snapshots>
      <enabled>true</enabled>
    </snapshots>
  </repository>
</repositories>
```

And flip the `spring.version` to `4.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT`

I have forked your project and updated [it here](https://github.com/snicoll/spring-cache-test) so that it works as it should. [Checking what I've changed](https://github.com/snicoll/spring-cache-test/commit/e7795fac51869b062a66e50d0b6768a956118141) would help you understand what was missing.

NOTE: your JSR-107 cache manager is wrong. You should create a `javax.cache.CacheManager` and once you have it you should wrap it to a Spring's `CacheManager`. Keep in mind you could just as well declare **any** `CacheManager` there and it would work (`SimpleCacheManager`, `GuavaCacheManager`, etc).

Comment: Hi ,I tried your suggestions and it shows this error:


java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot find cache named 'site' for CacheResultOperation[details[method=public com.test.cache.SitePojo com.test.cache.impl.SampleFacadeImpl.getCurrentSite(), cacheAnnotation=@javax.cache.annotation.CacheResult(cacheKeyGenerator=interface javax.cache.annotation.CacheKeyGenerator, cacheResolverFactory=interface javax.cache.annotation.CacheResolverFactory, cachedExceptions=[], skipGet=false, exceptionCacheName=, cacheName=site, nonCachedExceptions=[]), cacheName='site']]

Comment: Hi ,I tried your suggestions and it shows this error:Hi ,I tried your suggestions and it shows this error:

I saw in your scratch application you use SimpleCacheManager like this:
 SimpleCacheManager manager = new SimpleCacheManager();
manager.setCaches(asList(
new ConcurrentMapCache("default"),
new ConcurrentMapCache("another"))
);
return manager;
but unfortunately the JCacheCacheManager does not have setCaches method. How can I specify the caches for my JCacheCacheManager?

Comment: I think you should revisit `ehcache-jcache` and how it can be configured. This is probably a good idea to create another thread as this has nothing to do with Spring (it's a pure JSR-107 ehcache question). In the meantime you can use plain ehcache directly or look at my fork (I edited my original answer)